# change element value with lmxl python

Tags: python, lxml

I need to be able to parse a large xml file but only look for `<name>` elements and replace the value. Hence, I am doing event driven parsing as follows I have the following code:

```
import os, re, sys
from lxml import etree


# parse the xml file
context = etree.iterparse(xmlFile, events=('end',), tag='name')


for event, elem in context:

    # this is an internal method that I call to perform regex
    newElementText = searchReplace(elem.text).replace(" ", "")

    # assign the elem.text to the replaced value
    elem.text = newElementText

    # write to the xml
    etree.tostring(elem, encoding='utf-8')
```

My problem is with writing the updated element value to the file. When I call etree.tostring() it does not update the file. Can someone please kindly point to the error of my ways. Thanks!

Comment: It's not lxml (or even Python), but another option for performant, low-memory transforms of XML documents is STX: http://stx.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 0):

`etree.tostring(elem)` returns a string representation of the tree, so it does nothing in your code. Use `elem.write(xmlFile, encoding='utf-8')`.

Comment: Hi CharlesB. Thanks for the reply. I did try to use etree.write(); however, it does not seem to do the trick as it spits out the following error: etree.write(xmlFile)
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'write'

Comment: I had tried that as well, but was receiving the following error: elem.write()
AttributeError: 'lxml.etree._Element' object has no attribute 'write'. Could it be because I am not parsing the entire file? It is rather large and I only care to change the value of the <name> elements

Comment: If you're going to do an iterative parse, rather than storing the whole DOM tree in memory, you also need to do an iterative write (typically to a temp file, then renaming the temporary file over the original afterwards).

Comment: Charles, pardon my ignorance here, but if I do iterative write within the context that i am working on wouldn't the new file just contain the <name> elements. I need to be able to have the original file with the updated values for the <name> elements.